# Adding filter button to sort entries

Tags: sorting, ember.js, filter, javascript

So I have this query that pulls the data for me:

```
App.ListRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() { return $.getJSON('php/getlines.php'); }});
```

And I have in my handle bar this code to display it:

```
<tbody>
{{#each content}}
{{view App.lineItem contextBinding="this"}}
{{/each}}
</tbody>
```

I was thinking of making my html fields a button which when clicked would sort the entries:

```
<th class="center"{{action 'sortBy' 'invoice'}}>Invoice</td>
```

where there is a sort by function:

```
sortBy: function(property) {
  this.set('sortProperties', [property]);
  this.set('sortAscending', !this.get('sortAscending'));
 }
```

However, I keep getting this error:

Error: Nothing handled the event 'sortBy'.

I am not sure how I can have the entries sorted if I click that button?

Answer (score 0):

in the each loop, mention `itemController="ListsController"` and write the `sortBy` function in the ListsController.

Bascially with this you are indicating which controller the action should bubble up.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ajey mentions, you have to create a `ListsController` with a `sortBy` action. `sortBy` is already defined for `ArrayController` (see http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#method_sortBy) but I'm pretty sure adding an action of the same name won't override it.

```
App.ListsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    sortBy: function(property) {
      this.set('sortProperties', [property]);
      this.set('sortAscending', !this.get('sortAscending'));
    }
  }
});
```